# SVG animation inside svg:use element. Works in Firefox, not in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, d3.js, svg-animate

I'm using the `svg:use` element to embed an animating SVG spinner inside a large D3.js tree with many nodes.

One node looks like this:

```
<g class="node clickable" data-path="1" data-depth="0" transform="">
  <text class="title" x="0" y=".36em" style="fill-opacity: 1;" text-anchor="begin">Model</text>
  <text class="subtitle" x="0" y="2em" style="fill-opacity: 1;" text-anchor="begin">
  <use href="static/spinner.svg#spinner" transform="translate(54.75,-9) rotate(0 7,9)">
</g>
```

I use JQuery to insert the spinner when needed in the one of the many `g.node` elements in the tree.

The SVG source of the spinner is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="spinner" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="16px" height="16px">
  <g>
    <line x1="50" y1="3.167" x2="50" y2="23.5" opacity="0.2">
      <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.1" dur="1.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0s" />
    </line>
        <line x1="80.102" y1="14.124" x2="67.033" y2="29.7" opacity="0.2">
      <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.1" dur="1.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.1333s" />
    </line>    
        <line x1="96.121" y1="41.867" x2="76.096" y2="45.398" opacity="0.2">        
      <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.1" dur="1.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.2666s" />
    </line>
    <line  x1="90.559" y1="73.415" x2="72.949" y2="63.249" opacity="0.2">
      <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.1" dur="1.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.4s" />
    </line>     
        <line x1="66.018" y1="94.007" x2="59.064" y2="74.901" opacity="0.2">
      <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.1" dur="1.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.5333s" />
    </line>
    <line x1="33.983" y1="94.007" x2="40.937" y2="74.901" opacity="0.2">
      <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.1" dur="1.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.6666s" />
    </line>     
        <line x1="9.442" y1="73.417" x2="27.052" y2="63.25" opacity="0.2">
      <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.1" dur="1.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.8s" />
    </line>    
    <line x1="3.879" y1="41.868" x2="23.904" y2="45.399" opacity="0.2">
      <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.1" dur="1.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.9333s" />
    </line>    
    <line x1="19.897" y1="14.124" x2="32.966" y2="29.7" opacity="0.2">
      <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.1" dur="1.2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="1.0666s" />
    </line>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This works perfectly in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Safari. In Chrome and Safari, just the first 'frame' of the animation is shown, but the spinner is not animating.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: any chance you could post the full code or a link to a JSFiddle/bl.ocks.org version? It's a bit hard to see how your pieces all fit together.

Comment: Have you tried setting your attributeType="XML"

Comment: @MichaelMullany: I tried, but it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Chrome does not (automatically) play animations in embedded external SVG files, but I just found out it does when the SVG referenced by the `use` element is not loaded from an external file but from somewhere within the document.

A temporary solution could be as follows:

http://bl.ocks.org/bertspaan/6182774

Comment: one possible improvement on your temporary solution is to use the svg `<defs>` element instead of a hidden div. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092976/is-it-possible-to-import-svg-shapes-in-d3-js/18093866#18093866